# How are psychological bio-markers discovered?

Tags: neuroscience, measurement, abnormal-psychology, clinical-psychology

Recently, [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.jproteome.5b00434) [1] claiming to be able to distinguish bipolar disorder from major depressive disorder via a urine sample has come to my attention.

Despite reading the paper, I'm unable to understand how they discovered this bio-marker in the first place. What is the general procedure for identifying and verifying bio-markers in the domain of clinical psychology?

[1] "Divergent Urinary Metabolic Phenotypes between Major Depressive Disorder and Bipolar Disorder Identified by a Combined GC–MS and NMR Spectroscopic Metabonomic Approach" by Chen et. al

Comment: Is this question about the laboratory techniques (like GC-MS and NMR) or about the statistical processing of the measured data? Or were exactly is unclear after reading the paper?

Comment: A reference to a quick overview lab techniques and statistical processing would be ideal.